# Not able to read a property from .jnlp file

Tags: java, jar, java-web-start, jnlp

I am upgraded my java from 1.7.0.25 to 1.7.0.67. 
I have this in my jnlp file

```xml
<property name="ServerIP" value="10.124.0.120"/>
```

After upgrade I am getting null when I am trying to access this property using

```
System.getProperties().getProperty("ServerIP");
```

Any help?

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your JNLP file where the properties are.

Comment: Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0).